# What's the recommended way of manually indexing a record in OrientDB?

Tags: dictionary, indexing, nosql, orientdb

What's the recommended way of manually indexing a newly inserted record, and re-indexing a changed record, in OrientDB?

I know of the possibility of automatic indexes with OrientDB, but I need to map the indexed property to a lowercase version (for case insensitive search). So I will need to index records manually. Is it recommended/possible to make a database procedure to (re-)index a record?

Answer (score 0):

In OrientDB you've both:

- automatic indexes, updated by OrientDB (like RDBMS)
- manual indexes, on your charge, it's like a persistent map

For more information look at the official guide: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Indexes

Comment: Thanks, I realized upon re-reading that there are both automatic and manual indexes. Actually, I will need a manual index since the key must be lowercased (for case insensitivity) so I still need to know how to maintain the index.

Comment: I'm rephrasing my question to make it clear that I need to maintain a manual index.

Comment: You can set Collate=CI against index to be case insensitive

Comment: Would you mind just showing in your answer how to set Collate=CI on an automatic index (you mean an automatic index right?)?